# Vqmod xml script not working for opencart config.php

Tags: opencart

I am writing VQMod XML to edit config.php in opencart, i wrote below XML and saved it inside XML folder.

```
<modification>
<id>VQMOD CORE FOR OPENCART - DO NOT REMOVE</id>
<version>1.4.x and 1.5.x</version>
<vqmver>2.2.1</vqmver>
<author>Senthil</author>
<file name="./config.php">
    <operation>
         <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                    define('DB_PREFIX', 'op');
                    ]]></search>
         <add><![CDATA[
                    define('HTTP_IMAGE_2', 'http://localhost/opcart/image/');
                    define('HTTPS_IMAGE_2', 'http://localhost/opcart/image/');
                    define('DIR_IMAGE_2', '/Users/[username]/Sites/opcart/image/');
                    ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

But its not creating new cache file in vqcache folder as its doing for other files. No errors in log file. I have write permission to the vqcache folder and config file. Any help will be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vQmod's do not work on those files. It works basically on all php/tpl files above the index.php folder (ie 1 or more files deeper)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. You can use VQMod everywhere that a file is accessed, as long as there is a logical chain of "touch" to that file and no rogue `requires`. In this case, this is semi-untested beyond a dev instance, and there are "security" risks involved with making configs moddable.

To do it, you just need to edit index.php (and admin/index.php). Move the following to the top of of the index.php's (under define VERSION) so that it comes before the check for config.php's:

```
// VirtualQMOD
require_once('./vqmod/vqmod.php');
VQMod::bootup();
```

Then change the way OC is pulling config.php:

`require_once('config.php');`

By adding in the check for mods:

`require_once(VQMod::modCheck('config.php'));`

Access your catalog/admin so VQ can build, then check /vqmod/vqcache for file:

`vq2-config.php`

If it's there, and your changes are in, success.

PS: You can just use `<file name="config.php">` in your XML file, no need for the relative `./`.